# problem with dispic33 using DMA between UART and ADC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, uart, dma

I'm using dsPIC33FJ128MC804, i intend to read from ADC and send to UART but via the DMA ( direct memory access ) which is supported in that MCU , i use Mplabx c16 there is a problem with my code i can't figure it , i feel there is nothing wrong but the outcome is 100% nothing

```
#include <xc.h>

// FBS
#pragma config BWRP = WRPROTECT_OFF     // Boot Segment Write Protect (Boot Segment may be written)
#pragma config BSS = NO_FLASH           // Boot Segment Program Flash Code Protection (No Boot program Flash segment)
#pragma config RBS = NO_RAM             // Boot Segment RAM Protection (No Boot RAM)

// FSS
#pragma config SWRP = WRPROTECT_OFF     // Secure Segment Program Write Protect (Secure segment may be written)
#pragma config SSS = NO_FLASH           // Secure Segment Program Flash Code Protection (No Secure Segment)
#pragma config RSS = NO_RAM             // Secure Segment Data RAM Protection (No Secure RAM)

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Code Segment Write Protect (User program memory is not write-protected)
#pragma config GSS = OFF                // General Segment Code Protection (User program memory is not code-protected)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = PRI              // Oscillator Mode (Primary Oscillator (XT, HS, EC))
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Internal External Switch Over Mode (Start-up device with FRC, then automatically switch to user-selected oscillator source when ready)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = XT              // Primary Oscillator Source (XT Oscillator Mode)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function (OSC2 pin has clock out function)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON             // Peripheral Pin Select Configuration (Allow Only One Re-configuration)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor (Both Clock Switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor are disabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // WDT Prescaler (1:128)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON              // Watchdog Timer Enable (Watchdog timer always enabled)

// FPOR
#pragma config FPWRT = PWR128           // POR Timer Value (128ms)
#pragma config ALTI2C = OFF             // Alternate I2C  pins (I2C mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config LPOL = ON                // Motor Control PWM Low Side Polarity bit (PWM module low side output pins have active-high output polarity)
#pragma config HPOL = ON                // Motor Control PWM High Side Polarity bit (PWM module high side output pins have active-high output polarity)
#pragma config PWMPIN = ON              // Motor Control PWM Module Pin Mode bit (PWM module pins controlled by PORT register at device Reset)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD1               // Comm Channel Select (Communicate on PGC1/EMUC1 and PGD1/EMUD1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Port Enable (JTAG is Disabled)

#define FCY 4000000UL
#include <libpic30.h>


char  HReading ; char LReading ; int dummy ; int dummy2 ; 

/*const char Name[]="UART works\n" ;
const char ADCs[]="ADC1 Reading is : " ;
const char maxvalue[]=" it is the maximum value ";
const char lowvalue[]=" it is the lowest value ";*/
unsigned int ADCreading __attribute__((space (dma))) ;


void __attribute__((interrupt(auto_psv))) _U1TXInterrupt(void)
{
 IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0 ; 
}
void __attribute__((interrupt(auto_psv))) _DMA0Interrupt(void)
{
    DMA1REQbits.FORCE=1 ; //Force a single DMA transfer 
    IFS0bits.DMA0IF = 0 ;
}
void __attribute__((interrupt(auto_psv))) _DMA1Interrupt(void)
{
    IFS0bits.DMA1IF = 0 ;
}
void __attribute__((interrupt(auto_psv))) _AD1Interrupt(void)
{
    IFS0bits.AD1IF = 0 ; 
}
 void UartConfig(void)
 {
    U1MODEbits.UARTEN=0; //disable  UART 
    U1MODEbits.BRGH=0 ; //  Speed Low
    U1BRG = 12 ; // 9600 
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL=00 ; // 8-bit data , no parity 
    U1MODEbits.STSEL=0 ; // 1 stop bit 
    U1STAbits.URXISEL= 0b00 ; // Interrupt flag bit is set when a character is received
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL0 = 1 ; U1STAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0 ;  // Interrupt is generated when the last transmission is over (that is, the last character is shifted out of the Transmit Shift register) and all the transmit operations are completed
    U1MODEbits.USIDL=0 ; //continue operation in idle mode
    U1MODEbits.IREN=0 ; //IrDA encoder and decoder are disabled , works only at low baud 
    U1MODEbits.RTSMD= 1 ; // RTS simplex mode , no flow control
    U1MODEbits.UEN=00 ; // UxTX and UxRX pins are enabled and used; UxCTS, UxRTS and BCLKx pins are  controlled by port latches
    U1MODEbits.WAKE= 1 ;//  wake-up is enabled
    U1MODEbits.LPBACK = 0 ; // loopback mode is disabled 
    U1MODEbits.ABAUD=0 ; // Baud rate measurement disabled or completed

    U1STAbits.UTXINV = 0 ; // ?? UxTx idle state is 0 if IREN = 0  Transmit Polarity Inversion bit 
    U1STAbits.UTXBRK = 0 ; // 0 = Sync Break transmission is disabled or completed

   U1STAbits.ADDEN = 0 ; // Address Detect mode disabled
    // U1RXREG Receive Register 
    // U1TXREG Transmit Register 
 OSCCON=0x46 ; 
 OSCCON = 0x57 ;
 OSCCONbits.IOLOCK=0 ;  // unlock PPS sequence 
 RPOR11bits.RP23R=0b00011 ;  // PORTC7 as TX 
 RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 22 ; // c6 as RX 
OSCCON=0x46 ; 
OSCCON = 0x57 ;
OSCCONbits.IOLOCK=1 ;  // lock PPS sequence */
   U1MODEbits.UARTEN=1; //enable UART 
    U1STAbits.UTXEN =1  ; // UARTx transmitt is enabled 

 }

  void InterruptConfig()
{
     // clear the flag after configuration 
    SRbits.IPL=000 ;   /* CPU operates at 0 level priority NOTE : Each peripheral 
    interrupt source can be assigned to one of seven priority levels. to disable all set it 111 */
    INTCON1bits.NSTDIS=0 ;                 // Int nesting is enabled 
    INTCON2bits.ALTIVT=0;                   // Use standard (default) vector table
    INTCON2bits.INT0EP= 1;   
    INTCON2bits.INT1EP= 1;
    INTCON2bits.INT2EP= 1;// External interrupt 0 & 1 & 2 are negative edge triggerred



    IEC0bits.AD1IE = 1 ; IEC0bits.DMA0IE = 1 ; IEC0bits.DMA1IE = 1 ; IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 1 ; 
}
  void UartSend(char a)
  {
      U1TXREG = a ; 

      while ( U1STAbits.TRMT!=1)   // Transmit Shift Register is Empty bit  1 = empty 
      { 
      }
  }
  void ADCconfig(void)
  {
      AD1CON1bits.ADON = 0 ; // ADC disabled 
      AD1CON1bits.ADSIDL = 0 ;  // Continue module operation in idle mode 
      AD1CON1bits.ADDMABM = 1 ; // 1 = DMA buffers are written in the order of conversion. The module provides an address to the DMA channel that is the same as the address used for the non-DMA stand-alone buffer
      AD1CON1bits.AD12B = 1 ; // 12bit operation mode 1 channel 
      AD1CON1bits.FORM= 0b00 ; // right justified unsigned 
      AD1CON1bits.SSRC = 0b111 ; // Internal counter ends sampling and starts conversion (auto-convert)
      AD1CON1bits.SIMSAM=0 ; // Samples multiple channels individually in sequence
      AD1CON1bits.ASAM=1 ; // sample automaticaly after last conversion  Automatic trigger 
      /*DONE: ADC Conversion Status bit
1 = ADC conversion cycle is completed
0 = ADC conversion not started or in progress*/
      AD1CON2bits.VCFG=0b000 ; // reference VDD VSS
      AD1CON2bits.CSCNA = 0 ; // do not scan inputs
      AD1CON2bits.SMPI=0b0000; // Increments the DMA address after completion of every sample/conversion operation

        AD1CON2bits.BUFM=0; //Always starts filling the buffer from the start address
AD1CON2bits.ALTS=0 ;//  Always uses channel input selects for Sample A 
AD1CON3bits.ADRC = 0 ; // Clock Derived from System Clock 
AD1CON3bits.SAMC= 0 ; //sample =  Tad 
      AD1CON3bits.ADCS=0b100 ; // 4TCY = TAD the least Tad = 117.6 nano second , 
      AD1CON4bits.DMABL = 000 ; // 001 = Allocates 1 words of buffer to each analog input 
      AD1PCFGLbits.PCFG5=0; //Analog
       AD1PCFGLbits.PCFG6=0 ; //Analog 
        AD1PCFGLbits.PCFG1=0; //Analog
        AD1CHS0bits.CH0SA= 1; //Channel 0 positive input is 5 
                AD1CHS0bits.CH0NA= 0 ; //Channel 0 negative input is VREFL
        //ADCxBUF0 

  }
  void UartSendString(char* x )
  {
      while((*x)!='\0')
      {
          U1TXREG = *x ;

          while ( U1STAbits.TRMT!=1)   // Transmit Shift Register is Empty bit  1 = empty 
          {}
          x++ ;
      }
  }
  void DMAconfig(void)
  {
      // Channel 0  reads from ADC 
      DMA0CONbits.CHEN=0 ; //channel disabled 
            DMA0REQbits.IRQSEL=0b0001101 ; //ADC1 

      DMA0CONbits.SIZE = 0 ; // word ; 
      DMA0CONbits.DIR=0 ; // Read from peripheral and write to DPSRAM 
      DMA0CONbits.HALF = 0 ; // Initiate interrupt when all of the data has been moved
      DMA0CONbits.NULLW=0 ; // Normal operation 
      DMA0CONbits.AMODE = 0b01 ; // Register Indirect without Post-Increment mode
      DMA0CONbits.MODE= 00 ; // continuous no ping pong 
      DMA0REQbits.FORCE=0 ; //Auto
      DMA0PAD =(unsigned int )  &ADC1BUF0  ; 
      DMA0STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(&ADCreading) ;
      DMA0CNT=0 ;  // only one element ;
      IFS0bits.DMA0IF = 0;   //clear flag 

      // channel 1 to send to UART 

      DMA1CONbits.CHEN=0 ; //channel disabled  
      DMA1REQbits.IRQSEL =0b0001100 ;   // uart tX 
      DMA1CONbits.SIZE = 0 ; // word ; 
      DMA1CONbits.DIR=1 ; // Read from DPSRAM address, write to peripheral address
      DMA1CONbits.HALF = 0 ; // Initiate interrupt when all of the data has been moved
      DMA1CONbits.NULLW=0 ; // Normal operation 
      DMA1CONbits.AMODE = 0b01 ; // Register Indirect without Post-Increment mode
      DMA1CONbits.MODE= 00 ; // continuous no ping pong 

     DMA1PAD = ( unsigned int) &U2TXREG;
     DMA1STA=__builtin_dmaoffset(&ADCreading) ;
      DMA1CNT=0 ;  // only one element ;
     IFS0bits.DMA1IF=0 ;    //clear flag 
     DMA0CONbits.CHEN=1 ; //channel enabled  
     DMA1CONbits.CHEN=1 ; //channel enabled   

  }
int main ()
{ 
 I2C1CONbits.I2CEN=0;//Disables the I2Cx module. All I2C? pins are controlled by port functions
 PMCONbits.PMPEN = 0 ; // PMP is disabled  
 P2TCONbits.PTEN=0 ; // PWM time base is off 
 PWM2CON1bits.PEN1H=0;  //  disable PWM pins 
 PWM2CON1bits.PEN1L = 0 ; // 
 TRISCbits.TRISC8=0 ; // Red led output 
 TRISCbits.TRISC9=0 ; // Green led output 
 TRISCbits.TRISC7=0 ; 
 PORTCbits.RC9=1 ; //G LED on 
 PORTCbits.RC8 = 1 ; // R ON 
 InterruptConfig() ;
DMAconfig(); 
ADCconfig() ;
AD1CON1bits.ADON = 1 ; // ADC ON 
 __delay_us(100) ;
UartConfig() ;
      DMA0REQbits.FORCE=1 ; 

while (1)
{

  }
```

}

Comment: unsigned int ADCreading __attribute__((space (dma))) ;..........if this is a variable for your adc value..simply define int ADCredaing. and check

Comment: no , because that must be allocated in the DMA if you just defined it that way the memory address maybe out the DMA authority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries at last it works , the code for anyone who wants it :

```
#include <xc.h>

// FBS
#pragma config BWRP = WRPROTECT_OFF     // Boot Segment Write Protect (Boot Segment may be written)
#pragma config BSS = NO_FLASH           // Boot Segment Program Flash Code Protection (No Boot program Flash segment)
#pragma config RBS = NO_RAM             // Boot Segment RAM Protection (No Boot RAM)

// FSS
#pragma config SWRP = WRPROTECT_OFF     // Secure Segment Program Write Protect (Secure segment may be written)
#pragma config SSS = NO_FLASH           // Secure Segment Program Flash Code Protection (No Secure Segment)
#pragma config RSS = NO_RAM             // Secure Segment Data RAM Protection (No Secure RAM)

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Code Segment Write Protect (User program memory is not write-protected)
#pragma config GSS = OFF                // General Segment Code Protection (User program memory is not code-protected)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = PRI              // Oscillator Mode (Primary Oscillator (XT, HS, EC))
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Internal External Switch Over Mode (Start-up device with FRC, then automatically switch to user-selected oscillator source when ready)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = XT              // Primary Oscillator Source (XT Oscillator Mode)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function (OSC2 pin has clock out function)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON             // Peripheral Pin Select Configuration (Allow Only One Re-configuration)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor (Both Clock Switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor are disabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // WDT Prescaler (1:128)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON              // Watchdog Timer Enable (Watchdog timer always enabled)

// FPOR
#pragma config FPWRT = PWR128           // POR Timer Value (128ms)
#pragma config ALTI2C = OFF             // Alternate I2C  pins (I2C mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config LPOL = ON                // Motor Control PWM Low Side Polarity bit (PWM module low side output pins have active-high output polarity)
#pragma config HPOL = ON                // Motor Control PWM High Side Polarity bit (PWM module high side output pins have active-high output polarity)
#pragma config PWMPIN = ON              // Motor Control PWM Module Pin Mode bit (PWM module pins controlled by PORT register at device Reset)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD1               // Comm Channel Select (Communicate on PGC1/EMUC1 and PGD1/EMUD1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Port Enable (JTAG is Disabled)

#define FCY 4000000UL
#include <libpic30.h>
int dummy ; int dummy2 ;
char flag =0;
char LReading , HReading ;
unsigned int ADCreading[1] __attribute__((space (dma))) ;
unsigned char UARTsignal[2] __attribute__((space (dma))) ;
void interruptconf(void)
{
   SRbits.IPL=000 ;   /* CPU operates at 0 level priority NOTE : Each peripheral 
    interrupt source can be assigned to one of seven priority levels. to disable all set it 111 */
    INTCON1bits.NSTDIS=1 ;                 // Int nesting is disabled  
    INTCON2bits.ALTIVT=0;                   // Use standard (default) vector table 
    IEC0bits.AD1IE = 0 ; IEC0bits.DMA0IE = 1 ; IEC0bits.DMA1IE = 1 ; IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0 ; 
    IFS0bits.AD1IF=0 ; IFS0bits.DMA0IF=0 ; IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0 ; IFS0bits.DMA1IF=0 ;
}
void ADCconf(void)
{
    AD1CON1bits.ADON = 0 ; // ADC disabled 
    AD1CON1bits.ADDMABM = 1 ; // 1 = DMA buffers are written in the order of conversion. The module provides an address to the DMA channel that is the same as the address used for the non-DMA stand-alone buffer
    AD1CON1bits.AD12B = 1 ; // 12bit operation mode 1 channel 
    AD1CON1bits.FORM= 0b00 ; // right justified unsigned 
    AD1CON1bits.SSRC = 0b111 ; // Internal counter ends sampling and starts conversion (auto-convert)
    AD1CON1bits.ASAM=1 ; // sample automaticaly after last conversion  Automatic trigger 
    AD1CON2bits.VCFG=0b000 ; // reference VDD VSS
    AD1CON2bits.CSCNA = 0 ; // do not scan inputs
    AD1CON2bits.SMPI=0b0000; // Increments the DMA address after completion of every sample/conversion operation
    AD1CON2bits.BUFM=0; //Always starts filling the buffer from the start address
    AD1CON2bits.ALTS=0 ;//  Always uses channel input selects for Sample A 
    AD1CON3bits.ADRC = 0 ; // Clock Derived from System Clock 
    AD1CON3bits.SAMC= 2 ; //
    AD1CON3bits.ADCS=0b100 ; // 4TCY = TAD the least Tad = 117.6 nano second , 
    AD1CON4bits.DMABL = 000 ; // 001 = Allocates 1 words of buffer to each analog input 
    AD1PCFGLbits.PCFG5=0; //Analog
    AD1PCFGLbits.PCFG6=0 ; //Analog 
    AD1PCFGLbits.PCFG1=0; //Analog
    AD1CHS0bits.CH0SA= 0b00001; //Channel 0 positive input is 5 
    AD1CHS0bits.CH0NA= 0 ; //Channel 0 negative input is VREFL
}
void UartSend(char a)
  {
      U1TXREG = a ; 

      while ( U1STAbits.TRMT!=1)   // Transmit Shift Register is Empty bit  1 = empty 
      { 
      }

  }
void UARTconf(void)
{
    U1MODEbits.UARTEN=0; //disable  UART 
    U1MODEbits.BRGH=0 ; //  Speed Low
    U1BRG = 12 ; // 9600 
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL=00 ; // 8-bit data , no parity 
    U1MODEbits.STSEL=0 ; // 1 stop bit 
    U1STAbits.URXISEL= 0b00 ; // Interrupt flag bit is set when a character is received
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL0 = 0 ; 
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL1 = 0 ;  // Interrupt generated when any character is transferred to the Transmit Shift register (which ast one location is empty in the transmit buffer)
    U1MODEbits.USIDL=0 ; //continue operation in idle mode
    U1MODEbits.IREN=0 ; //IrDA encoder and decoder are disabled , works only at low baud 
    U1MODEbits.RTSMD= 1 ; // RTS simplex mode , no flow control
    U1MODEbits.UEN=00 ; // UxTX and UxRX pins are enabled and used; UxCTS, UxRTS and BCLKx pins are  controlled by port latches
    U1MODEbits.WAKE= 1 ;//  wake-up is enabled
    U1MODEbits.LPBACK = 0 ; // loopback mode is disabled 
    U1MODEbits.ABAUD=0 ; // Baud rate measurement disabled or completed
    U1STAbits.UTXINV = 0 ; // ?? UxTx idle state is 0 if IREN = 0  Transmit Polarity Inversion bit 
    U1STAbits.UTXBRK = 0 ; // 0 = Sync Break transmission is disabled or completed
   U1STAbits.ADDEN = 0 ; // Address Detect mode disabled

}
void DMA0conf(void)
{   //for ADC 
    DMA0CONbits.CHEN=0 ; //channel disabled 
    DMA0PAD =(volatile unsigned int ) &ADC1BUF0  ; 
    DMA0CNT=0 ;  // only one element ;
    DMA0REQbits.IRQSEL=0b0001101 ;  //ADC 
     DMA0STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(ADCreading) ;
    IFS0bits.DMA0IF = 0;   //clear flag 
    DMA0CONbits.SIZE = 0 ; // word ; 
    DMA0CONbits.DIR=0 ; //   ADC to ram 
    DMA0CONbits.HALF = 0 ; // Initiate interrupt when all of the data has been moved
    DMA0CONbits.NULLW=0 ; // Normal operation 
    DMA0CONbits.AMODE = 0b01 ; // Register Indirect without Post-Increment mode
    DMA0CONbits.MODE= 00 ; // continuous no ping pong 
    DMA0REQbits.FORCE=0 ; //Auto
    DMA0CONbits.CHEN=1 ; //channel enabled  

}
void DMA1conf(void)
{  // for TX 
  DMA1CONbits.CHEN=0 ; //channel disabled 
    DMA1REQbits.IRQSEL=0b0001100 ; 
    DMA1PAD =(volatile unsigned int ) &U1TXREG ; 
     DMA1CNT=1 ;  // only two element ;
    DMA1STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(UARTsignal) ;

    IFS0bits.DMA1IF = 0;   //clear flag 
    DMA1CONbits.SIZE = 1 ; // byte ; 
    DMA1CONbits.DIR=1 ; // RAM to TX 
    DMA1CONbits.HALF = 0 ; // Initiate interrupt when all of the data has been moved
    DMA1CONbits.NULLW=0 ; // Normal operation 
    DMA1CONbits.AMODE = 0b00 ; // Register Indirect with Post-Increment mode
    DMA1CONbits.MODE= 00 ; // continuous no ping pong 
    DMA1REQbits.FORCE=0 ; //Auto
    DMA1CONbits.CHEN=1 ; //channel enabled      
}
void __attribute__((interrupt(no_auto_psv))) _DMA0Interrupt(void)
{
    PORTCbits.RC8 = 1 ; // R ON

    if(flag == 1 )
    {
    dummy =ADCreading[0] ;
    dummy2 = (0b0000000011111111 & dummy );
    LReading = dummy2 ; 
    dummy2=0b1111111100000000&dummy ;
    dummy2=dummy2>>8 ;
    HReading= dummy2 ; 
    UARTsignal[1]=HReading; UARTsignal[0]=LReading ; 
    flag=0;
    }
     IFS0bits.DMA0IF = 0 ;
}
void __attribute__((interrupt(no_auto_psv))) _DMA1Interrupt(void)
{
    flag = 1 ; 
    PORTCbits.RC9 = 1 ;
    IFS0bits.DMA1IF = 0 ;
}
void __attribute__((interrupt(no_auto_psv))) _U1TXInterrupt(void)
{
 IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0 ; 
}
int main()
{

    I2C1CONbits.I2CEN=0;//Disables the I2Cx module. All I2C? pins are controlled by port functions
 PMCONbits.PMPEN = 0 ; // PMP is disabled  
 P2TCONbits.PTEN=0 ; // PWM time base is off 
 PWM2CON1bits.PEN1H=0;  //  disable PWM pins 
 PWM2CON1bits.PEN1L = 0 ; // 
 OSCCON=0x46 ; 
 OSCCON = 0x57 ;
 OSCCONbits.IOLOCK=0 ;  // unlock PPS sequence 
 RPOR11bits.RP23R=0b00011 ;  // PORTC7 as TX 
 RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 22 ; // c6 as RX 
OSCCON=0x46 ; 
OSCCON = 0x57 ;
OSCCONbits.IOLOCK=1 ;  // lock PPS sequence */
 TRISCbits.TRISC8=0 ; // Red led output 
 TRISCbits.TRISC9=0 ; // Green led output 
 PORTCbits.RC8 = 0 ; // R OFF  
 PORTCbits.RC9 = 0 ;
interruptconf() ; 
 DMA0conf() ;
 DMA1conf() ; 
 ADCconf() ;
 UARTconf() ; 
AD1CON1bits.ADON = 1 ; // ADC enabled
__delay_ms(100) ;
U1MODEbits.UARTEN=1; //enable UART 
U1STAbits.UTXEN =1  ; // UARTx transmitt is enabled 
 DMA1REQbits.FORCE=1 ; //Auto
    while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Without any explanation of what the issue(s) were, this is completely useless.

Comment: You changed SAMC from 0 to 2. The datasheet says it should be at least 1 when SSRC = 0b111. Do you think this was the problem? If not, what _did_ you change that got it working?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't remember acutally
@DaveTweed i don't know, sorry sometimes i just recode from scratch and it works, plus i've not code  dispic  long time ago.